# Current direction from previous location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have two coordinates, current and previous locations. what I want to do is to use bearingTo() method to see the direction of the new current location from the previous one, like this:

```
float bearing = prevLoc.bearingTo(newLoc);
```

I want to find the direction if it's north, south, ... and if it is the oppiste direction of the previous location, I want to change the marker's icon for example.

but I don't know how to calculate it from the resulted float, can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Surely you can figure out how to convert from degrees to cardinal compass directions.  The linked question seems to allege they might sometimes be negative, in which case you can add 360 until you get a value between 0 and 360.

Comment: @ChrisStratton for example I got -111.33706, I add 360 to this number ?

Comment: Yes, and you get a direction to the West and a little bit to the South.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Uhaa! Thanks a lot for the help!